# How to print user details in postman API directly from submitting the submit button in front end part using express,nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I want to print user response directly in postman from through submitting the submit button .

the above is my code

```
import express from "express";
import {dirname} from 'path';
import {fileURLToPath} from "url";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import fs from "fs";

const __dirname=dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/index.html");
});

app.post("/submit",(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    const { email, name,password } = req.body;

   
  
  
fs.appendFile("file.txt",`${email},${name},${password}\n`,(err)=>{
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("file saved success");
    res.redirect("/");
});
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(" port running on 3000");
  });
```

i tried many solutions given from the chatgpt but its all are not working

Answer (score 0):

This code from `express` will print to Postman for user detail information.

```
    res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'User registered successfully',
        user: newUser
    });
```

##### Overview

[image]

##### `Express Side`

`Express Side`: Multer is middleware for handling multipart/form-data, commonly used for uploading files. It allows Express to parse form data sent in POST requests that contain files. cors, along with CORS middleware, enables handling multipart/form-data requests and managing Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policies. It will be no problem from HTML POST call.

`FormData`: When a form with enctype multipart/form-data is submitted from the client-side, it sends data as a FormData object. This format allows sending files and non-text data, like JSON, as well.

`Response POST by JSON`: Despite the form data being sent in multipart/form-data format, Express can still respond with JSON. After processing the form data with Multer, Express can send JSON data back to the client, typically containing information about the success or failure of the request.

`Middleware Integration`: Multer is integrated into the Express middleware stack with app.use(multer().none()). This setup allows Express to parse form data sent in POST requests and make it accessible in the req.body object.

`JSON Response`: After processing the form data, Express can send a JSON response using res.json(). This response can contain any relevant data, such as a success message, error details, or processed form data, which the client-side JavaScript can then handle accordingly.

##### `Browser Side`

HTML side
`JSON Display`: JavaScript code fetches JSON data from the server and displays it in a readable format on the HTML page.

`Form Data` for POST Call: HTML form collects user input (email, username, password), and JavaScript sends it as JSON in an HTTP POST request to the server.

`Response Handling`: JavaScript waits for and receives a JSON response from the server, which it then displays on the HTML page.

This code will works.

##### Files structure

[image]

##### `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>User Registry</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        #container {
            width: 400px;
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .form-group {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 8px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        button {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px 0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: none;
            background-color: #007bff;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        button:hover {
            background-color: #0056b3;
        }

        pre {
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            overflow-x: auto;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form id="userForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="emailInput" name="email" value="tom_cruise@test.com" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="username" value="tom_cruise" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="passwordInput" name="password" value="1234" required>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="button">Register</button>
        </form>
        <pre id="meaning"></pre>
    </div>
    <script>
        const button = document.querySelector("#button");
        const meaning = document.querySelector("#meaning");

        button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
            const email = document.querySelector("#emailInput").value;
            const username = document.querySelector("#nameInput").value;
            const password = document.querySelector("#passwordInput").value;

            const url = `http://localhost:3000/register`;

            try {
                const response = await fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ email, username, password })
                });
                const data = await response.json();

                displayMeanings(data);
            } catch (error) {
                meaning.innerHTML = `<p>Error fetching data: ${error.message}</p>`;
            }
        });

        function displayMeanings(data) {
            meaning.textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

##### `server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const cors = require('cors'); // Import cors module
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

function readUsersFromFile() {
    try {
        const data = fs.readFileSync('users_log.json', 'utf8');
        return JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (err) {
        return [];
    }
}

function writeUsersToFile(users) {
    fs.writeFileSync('users_log.json', JSON.stringify(users, null, 2), 'utf8');
}

const upload = multer();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors());


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// POST route for registering users
app.post('/register', upload.none(), (req, res) => {
    const { email, username, password } = req.body;

    // You can perform validation here

    const newUser = { email, username, password };
    
    let users = readUsersFromFile();
    
    users.push(newUser);
    
    writeUsersToFile(users);

    // Send JSON response for the newly registered user
    res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'User registered successfully',
        user: newUser
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

##### Install dependencies

```bash
npm install express body-parser multer cors
```

##### Running server

```
node server.js
```

##### API test by Postman

[image]

##### Registry

Open Browser and enter user's credential and Press button

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

##### Result

[image]

In users_log.json

```
[
  {
    "email": "tom_cruise@test.com",
    "username": "tom_cruise",
    "password": "1234"
  },
  {
    "email": "michael jackson@test.com",
    "username": "michael_jackson",
    "password": "1234"
  }
]
```